# apex_item_text Add Row/Remove Row Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am working with Apex_Item_Text .. i am using the below query to display the text area in apex as null initially.

```
 select distinct a.GUID, a.CREATED_BY, a.created_date, apex_item.text(null)

 Delete from 
 NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUP_MEMBERS a,
 NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUPS b
 where a.DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID in 
      (select DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID from NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUPS 
       where instr(','||DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID||',' , ','||:P153_ID_HIDDEN||',') > 0) ;`
```

In Apex application once the text area filled by user as Delete/Add, it has to update in table when submit button pressed, i don't know how to proceed further on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a number into the apex_item.text function. By passing a number APEX will automatically create an array that will store the values of those columns.

This can be referenced in your delete statement with: APEX_APPLICATION.G_FXX(i) where XX is the number you pass into the apex_item.text function and i is the index of the item.

Without passing a number into the apex_item.text function I would have no idea how to reference that field

See oracle documentation for more information about apex_item.text: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI211